# Substring in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I have a quick question.
I'm studying some SQL exercises, and one of them, I need to remove the number from a street name.

For example:

- 5026 S CRENSHAW BLVD - **Should be CRENSHAW**
- 2635 WHITTIER BLVD - **Should be WHITTIER**
- 308 WESTWOOD PLZ # 1390L - **Should Be WESTWOOD**
- 1111 WILSHIRE BLVD - **Should be WILSHIRE**

Then, the answer to treat the address above was like this:

```
substring(facility_address FROM '[\d]+\s?\w?\s([\w]+)\s?')
```

I would like to understand how the substring works, what does it means de [\D] etc.

Could someone explain?
Thank you very much indeed! :)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on regular expressions.

`'[\d]+\s?\w?\s([\w]+)\s?'` is a regular expression.

I'll try to break it down:

First of all, these are quantifiers:

`+` means one or more

`?` means one or none

And now for the regular expression:

`[\d]+` matches one or more digits. I think the square brackets are actually not necessary here.

`\s?` optionally matches a whitespace character (optionally meaning it may or may not be there)

`\w?` optionally matches a word character

`\s` matches a whitespace character, but this time it's not optional since there is no `?` at the end

`([\w]+)` matches one or more word characters. Notice the parenthesis which denote a so called 'capture group`. Everything within the parenthesis is actually returned by the substring function.